# Interview - Test Values

Tags: unit-testing, computer-science

Ok, let's assume that I have a function that checks to see which is the most repeated number in a given array.

This function then needs to be tested, and, need to be tested using particular values in order to make sure that the function worked correctly (Unit testing) - What are these values? I'm confused.

P.s Why should I need to use these values, why couldn't I just debug the code, or, write it on pen and paper to see what the result SHOULD be and then match it against the value outputted?

Comment: I'm assuming the unit test case supplies the necessary values in the interview question.

Comment: @Tejs No, it was just what values COULD you use.. Apparently there specific values

Comment: If you know there are specific test cases you must write for specific values, I'm not sure what your question is then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Corner cases.

*Can it handle negatives *

```
Array = [-5, -5, -5, 5, 5, 5, 5] expected : 5
Array = [-5, -5, -5, -5, 5, 5, 5] expected : -5
```

*How does it handle ambiguous cases*

```
Array = [1,1,1,2,2,2] expected = ?? (See spec for expected)
Array = [1,2,3,4,5,6] expected = ??
```

*How does it handle arbitrarily large ints*

```
Array = [999999999999999, 999999999999999, 999999999999999, -99999999999999999]
expected = 999999999999999;
```

*How does it handle arbitrarily large Arrays*

```
Array = [0,0] + {i : 1 < i < 9999999999999, i is an int }
expected = 0;
```

*How does it handle nulls*

```
Array = null; 
expected = null; 

Array = [null, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
expected = 3;

Array = [null, null, null, 1, 2, 3, 3]
Expected = null or 3 depending on spec.
```

Why units test and not just debug ?

1.) debugging assumes you know there error is there already. If we always knew about all errors just by looking at the code we wouldn't need to test at all would we?

2.) Often times we are more interested in the undefined areas of a functions spec then the errors in the code. You never told me how you handle null values in the array... You'll need to specify that in your spec before your api is 'complete'

3.)For this particular function working it out by hand is easy. But what if you are computing the determinate of the jacobian matrix of a function? You don't really want to do that on paper do you?

4.) In an enterprise environment formalized testing prevents teams from cutting corners during crunch times, which can be very damaging to companies, and net sum will increase development time rather then decrease it due to reduced stability in code.

Comment: but the thing is, they actually didn't give me any test cases. It was just, I have a function that finds the most common number in an array, what /test values/ can I use to check to see if the function is working properly? So in my head I assumed that, d = {4, 4, 2, 1, 0} = 4; but they didn't like this answer

Comment: The idea isn't to try just one. The idea is to TRY to break the algorithm on purpose. Throw everything you can think of that might cause an error. If you cant break it on purpose, then the chances of it breaking in the wild are far less. This encourages robust algorithms that have to be rewritten less often.

Answer (score 1):

The values are test values.  In your example you might have an array with a most frequent occurring [1,2,2,3], one with a tie [1,1,2,2,3], and an empty array [] to test the most interesting edge cases.